# iOS/Mac OS fluent matching framework that works with Swift?

Tags: swift, matcher, ochamcrest, expecta

Is there a fluent matching API that works for Swift code? The leading Objective-C matcher candidates seem to be OCHamcrest and Expecta, both of which rely on complex macros that ([as per the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithCAPIs.html)) aren't available to Swift code, e.g.

```
#define HC_assertThat(actual, matcher)  \
    HC_assertThatWithLocation(self, actual, matcher, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

(OCHamcrest)

```
#define EXP_expect(actual) _EXP_expect(self, __LINE__, __FILE__, ^id{ return EXPObjectify((actual)); })
```

(Expecta)

Is there another alternative that does work with Swift, or some way to wrap one or the other of these so they can be used with Swift?

---

**ETA:** For future readers -- I looked at [SwiftHamcrest](https://github.com/nschum/SwiftHamcrest) (per [Jon Reid's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26447716/27358)) but for the time being I've settled on [Quick/Nimble](https://github.com/Quick/Quick).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/nschum/SwiftHamcrest is a Swift-native implementation of Hamcrest

Answer (score 2):

Complex preprocessor macros aren't translated to their Swift alternatives. Apple has a Blog discussing Swift, [in which they described on how they made the assert function](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=15).

The first macro is easy to make into a Swift function

```
#define HC_assertThat(actual, matcher)  \
    HC_assertThatWithLocation(self, actual, matcher, __FILE__, __LINE__)
```

In Swift:

```
func HC_assertThat(caller: AnyObject, actual: String, matcher: String, file: String = __FILE__, line: UWord = __LINE__) {
    HC_assertThatWithLocation(caller, actual, matcher, file.fileSystemRepresentation, Int32(line))
}

#define EXP_expect(actual) _EXP_expect(self, __LINE__, __FILE__, ^id{ return EXPObjectify((actual)); })
```

In Swift:

```
func EXP_expect(caller: AnyObject, actual: String, line: UWord = __LINE__, file: String = __FILE__) {
    _EXP_expect(caller, Int32(line), file.fileSystemRepresentation, ({
        return EXPObjectify(caller)
    })
}
```

Note that I am guessing on what you want passed to the preprocessor functions.

Comment: For Expecta for some reason in swift _EXP_expect can be called but EXPObjectify and _EXPObjectify are not visible . I can see them declared in the objective-c header and I have imported this in to the bridging header but no luck. Any idea how to get it working?